# Swift: Is it possible to add a protocol extension to a protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols, extension-methods

Lets say I have two protocols:

```
protocol TheirPcol {}
protocol MyPcol {
    func extraFunc()
}
```

What I want to do is to create a protocol extension for 'TheirPcol' which lets `extraFunc()` work on anything which conforms to 'TheirPcol'. So something like this:

```
extension TheirPcol : MyPcol { // Error 'Extension of protocol 'TheirPcol' cannot have an inheritance clause.
    func extraFunc() { /* do magic */}
}

struct TheirStruct:TheirPcol {}
let inst = TheirStruct()
inst.extraFunc()
```

The kicker in this is that 'TheirPcol', 'TheirStruct' are all handled by an external API which I do not control. So I'm passed the instance 'inst'.

Can this be done? Or am I going to have to do something like this:

```
struct TheirStruct:TheirPcol {}
let inst = TheirStruct() as! MyPcol
inst.extraFunc()
```

Comment: I think extending `ThierPol` will be suitable.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It seems there are two use-cases of why you may want to do what you are doing. In the first use-case, Swift will allow you to do what you want, but not very cleanly in the second use-case. I'm guessing you fall into the second category, but I'll go through both.

## Extending the functionality of `TheirPcol`

One reason why you might want to do this is simply to give extra functionality to `TheirPcol`. Just like the compiler error says, you cannot extend Swift protocols to conform to other protocols. However, you can simply extend `TheirPcol`.

```
extension TheirPcol {
    func extraFunc() { /* do magic */ }
}
```

Here, you are giving all objects that conform to `TheirPcol` the method `extraFunc()` and giving it a default implementation. This accomplishes the task of extending functionality for the objects conforming to `TheirPcol`, and if you want it to apply to your own objects as well then you could conform your objects to `TheirPcol`. In many situations, however, you want to keep `MyPcol` as your primary protocol and just treat `TheirPcol` as conforming to `MyPcol`. Unfortunately, Swift does not currently support protocol extensions declaring conformance to other protocols.

## Using `TheirPcol` objects as if they were `MyPcol`

In the use case (most likely your use case) where you really do need the separate existence of `MyPcol`, then as far as I am aware there is no clean way to do what you want yet. Here's a few working but non-ideal solutions:

### Wrapper around `TheirPcol`

One potentially messy approach would be to have a `struct` or `class` like the following:

```
struct TheirPcolWrapper<T: TheirPcol>: MyPcol {
    var object: T

    func extraFunc() { /* Do magic using object */ }
}
```

You could theoretically use this struct as an alternative to casting, as in your example, when you need to make an existing object instance conform to `MyPcol`. Or, if you have functions that accept `MyPcol` as a generic parameter, you could create equivalent functions that take in `TheirPcol`, then convert it to `TheirPcolWrapper` and send it off to the other function taking in `MyPcol`.

Another thing to note is if you are being passed an object of `TheirPcol`, then you won't be able to create a `TheirPcolWrapper` instance without first casting it down to an explicit type. This is due to some generics limitations of Swift. So, an object like this could be an alternative:

```
struct TheirPcolWrapper: MyPcol {
    var object: MyPcol

    func extraFunc() { /* Do magic using object */ }
}
```

This would mean you could create a `TheirPcolWrapper` instance without knowing the explicit type of the `TheirPcol` you are given.

For a large project, though, both of these could get messy really fast.

### Extending individual objects using a child protocol

Yet another non-ideal solution is to extend each object that you know conforms to `TheirPcol` and that you know you wish to support. For example, suppose you know that `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` conform to `TheirPcol`. You could create a child protocol of `MyPcol` and then explicitly declare conformance for both objects, as below:

```
protocol BridgedToMyPcol: TheirPcol, MyPcol {}

extension BridgedToMyPcol {
    func extraFunc() {
        // Do magic here, given that the object is guaranteed to conform to TheirPcol
    }
}

extension ObjectA: BridgedToMyPcol {}
extension ObjectB: BridgedToMyPcol {}
```

Unfortunately, this approach breaks down if there are a large number of objects that you wish to support, or if you cannot know ahead of time what the objects will be. It also becomes a problem when you don't know the explicit type of a `TheirPcol` you are given, although you can use `type(of:)` to get a metatype.

## A note about Swift 4

You should check out [Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md#extending-protocols-to-conform-to-protocols), a proposal accepted for inclusion in Swift 4. Specifically, this proposal outlines the ability to have the following extension:

```
extension Array: Equatable where Element: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Array<Element>, rhs: Array<Element>) -> Bool { ... }
}
```

While this is not quite what you are asking, at the bottom you'll find "Alternatives considered", which has a sub-section called "Extending protocols to conform to protocols", which is much more what you're trying to do. It provides the following example:

```
extension Collection: Equatable where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then states the following:

> This protocol extension would make any Collection of Equatable elements Equatable, which is a powerful feature that could be put to good use. Introducing conditional conformances for protocol extensions would exacerbate the problem of overlapping conformances, because it would be unreasonable to say that the existence of the above protocol extension means that no type that conforms to Collection could declare its own conformance to Equatable, conditional or otherwise.

While I realize you're not asking for the ability to have *conditional* conformances, this is the closest thing I could find regarding discussion of protocols being extended to conform to other protocols.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed response. It certain helped my understanding of the problem. Unfortunately not having the ability to control the type of the object or the protocol being return limits what I can do. Luckily I've since managed to find a solution elsewhere in the code although I'd still like to be able to effectively use an extension to add functions to a protocol which comply with another protocol.