# Conditional Protocol Conformance to Protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I'm learning Swift coming from other languages with powerful type systems and I am wondering if their is any way to make a protocol conditionally conform to another protocol.

Let's take an example: I define a `ShowableAsInt` protocol, that allows to get an `Int` representation for any type that conforms to it.

```
protocol ShowableAsInt {
        func intRepr() -> Int
}

extension Int : ShowableAsInt {
    func intRepr() -> Int {
        return self
    }
}

extension String : ShowableAsInt {
    func intRepr() -> Int {
        return self.count
    }
}

func show(_ s: ShowableAsInt) {
    print(s.intRepr())
}

show("abc") // "3"
show(42) // "42"
```

Now I define a `Container` protocol that simply wraps an element.

```
protocol Container {
    associatedtype T
    var element: T {
        get
    }
}

struct StringContainer : Container {
    typealias T = String
    let element: String
}

struct IntContainer : Container {
    typealias T = Int
    let element: Int
}
```

Because `Container` is a simple wrapper, whenever the wrapped type can be shown as an `Int`, the container can also be shown as an `Int`. I tried to express this, but failed:

```
// Doesn't compile: can't extend a protocol to conform to another one?
extension Container : ShowableAsInt where T : ShowableAsInt {
    func intRepr() -> Int {
        return element.intRepr()
    }
}

// I would like these to compile
show(IntContainer(42)) // "42"
show(StringContainer("abc")) // "3"
```

I know that this conditional conformance can be expressed on `class` and `struct`. Is there any way to do the same for protocols? If not, is there any reason for this restriction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this is not allowed is stated [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md#extending-protocols-to-conform-to-protocols):

> This protocol extension would make any Collection of Equatable elements Equatable, which is a powerful feature that could be put to good use. Introducing conditional conformances for protocol extensions would exacerbate the problem of overlapping conformances, **because it would be unreasonable to say that the existence of the above protocol extension means that no type that conforms to Collection could declare its own conformance to Equatable**, conditional or otherwise.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993616/swift-is-it-possible-to-add-a-protocol-extension-to-a-protocol).

If you just don't want to write the duplicate implementation of `intRepr` everytime, you can do this:

```
struct StringContainer : ShowableAsIntContainer {
    typealias T = String
    let element: String
}

struct IntContainer : ShowableAsIntContainer {
    typealias T = Int
    let element: Int
}

extension Container where T : ShowableAsInt {
    func intRepr() -> Int {
        return element.intRepr()
    }
}

typealias ShowableAsIntContainer = ShowableAsInt & Container
```

Comment: Your alternative does the trick for this small example, but it breaks composability. In many realistic scenarios, `Container` is from a library, and I'm not in control of the declarations of `StringContainer` and `IntContainer`. So I cannot write "laws" about `Container` themselves, without having to explicitly apply these laws to every type that conforms to `Container`. It's quite a deep limitation of the type system and, even if I understand its "simplicity > complexity" motivation, it makes me kinda sad.

Comment: @francoisr Well, nothing is perfect.